# Switch excel sheets via barcode

Tags: excel, barcode-scanner

I am putting circuit boards with a barcode into a housing. The plan is to put a serial number on the housing eg. 000001, 000002, etc.

I would like to make a seperate excel sheet for each housing, sheet name 000001, 000002, etc.

Next I would like to have a barcode on each housing that when scanned commands excel to go to the corresponding sheet. Basically a command that says "goto sheet000001! A1", so the guys in the workshop can scan a housing followed by the circuit board numbers that go in that specific housing and therefore in the correct sheet...

So I get seperate sheets, each with the numbers of the used circuit boards in it?

Is this possible? Can I make excel go to a sheet immediately without pressing shortcuts?

If not, can I put the serial numbers in the columns, make excel jump to the right column through a scan action and scan the circuitboard numbers in the rows below it?
Thanks!

Comment: `Is this possible?` *probably*. What code or attempts do you have to share?